# Choose groups with consecutive year-quarters

Tags: r, date

I hope to choose the identifiers that have consecutive year-quarter records. For example, ID 111 will be selected because it has all year-quarters. ID 113 will be selected because the year-quarter combinations are consecutive, although the ID only has a portion of the total year-quarters. ID 112 will not be selected because the year-quarter is not consecutive. It lacks 201601, 201602, 201603.

```
Identifer   year-quarter
111          201503
111          201504
111          201601
111          201602
111          201603
111          201604
112          201503
112          201504
112          201604
113          201503
113          201504
113          201601
```

My current code (below) can only deal with selecting IDs that have the full year-quarter combinations. I wonder how to achieve my desired outcome.

```
df2 = group_by(df1, Identifer) %>% summarize(total = n()) %>% filter(total =6)
```

The desired outcome is

```
Identifer
111
113
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way , we could do this is by using `dplyr` and `lubridate` together. We can `group_by` `Identifier` and use `yq` function to convert year-quarter to date and then take difference between those consecutive dates and get all the groups where all the dates are in the range of 90-120 as maximum amount of days we can allow between one quarter.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  group_by(Identifer) %>%
  mutate(yearq = c(90, diff(yq(year.quarter)))) %>%
  filter(all(yearq > 89 & yearq < 120)) %>%
  select(Identifer) %>%
  unique()

#   Identifer
#      <int>
#1       111
#2       113
```

Answer (score 2):

To select 'Identifiers', convert 'year.quarter' to `zoo::year.qtr`, take difference between consecutive values by group, check if all differerences are 0.25*.

```
library(zoo)
tapply(as.yearqtr(as.character(d$year.quarter), format = "%Y%q"), d$Identifer,
       FUN = function(x) all(diff(as.numeric(x)) == 0.25))

# 111   112   113 
# TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

To select corresponding rows, use a similar logic with `ave`:

```
d[as.logical(ave(as.yearqtr(as.character(d$year.quarter), format = "%Y%q"), d$Identifer,
                 FUN = function(x) all(diff(x) == 0.25))), ]
#    Identifer year.quarter
# 1        111       201503
# 2        111       201504
# 3        111       201601
# 4        111       201602
# 5        111       201603
# 6        111       201604
# 10       113       201503
# 11       113       201504
# 12       113       201601
```

---

*From `?as.yearqtr`:

> The "`yearqtr`" class is used to represent quarterly data. Internally it holds the data as year plus 0 for Quarter 1, 1/4 for Quarter 2 and so on

---

The post was improved by comments from @G.Grothendieck. Thanks!